# Allow current dagrun to complete and disable all subsequent runs

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x, mwaa

We have a dag that is scheduled to run every 30 minutes. The systems that the dag run uses (eg: MySql db) sometimes have to be taken offline (maintenance, patching, etc). What we would like to do is allow any dagruns that are currently "running" to complete but to not allow any subsequent runs.

Pausing/Disabling the DAG doesnt work, as it sets the next task that is to run to a state of "scheduled" and does not let the current dag-run to complete. What I am looking for is a way to let the entire current running dag-run to complete and no subsequent dag-runs to be triggered.

[image]

Seems like such "patching" work is probably something others need to do and I was wondering how you handle this situation, without adding a skip-step (eg: ShortCircuitOperator), that checks for a flag being set and skips subsequent runs. Ideally I was hoping for some kind of a Airflow or Dag level setting that allows us to basically allow the DAG to drain itself and not allow any new instances of DagRuns.

Comment: This use case is currently not supported. I suggest to create a feature request for it in the open source: https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues

Comment: If you raise it please post a link here. I strongly support the need to separate the two features (stop scheduling the DAG vs stop executing its tasks in already scheduled DAG runs).

Comment: I don't understand your Use Case. If your DB is Offline, your DAG runs will fail. You can then retry them when your DB is back online. You can also Pause your DAG and mark all running tasks to FAIL state in order to retry them later.

Comment: Hi @vdolez, what I want to do is "drain" all executing jobs, so that I can take the db offline. If I pause the DAG, then the currently executing task completes, but not the entire dag. And while I could take the DB offline and let the tasks go into fail state, it feels like it would be great to put a DAG into a state that allows for it to complete and not retrigger on its schedule.

Comment: Here is the use-case as an issue: https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/36539